# Problems decoding a gstreamer pipeline into images using node.js

Tags: node.js, image-processing, ffmpeg, video-streaming, gstreamer

I have this Gstreamer pipeline that launches a test video , encodes it in h264 and sends it via udp on localhost 5000.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I run this pipeline in my terminal.

Then I have a minimalistic node.js server that is suposed to receive the udp stream coming from the gstreamer pipeline, decode the video into images.
Finally I emit each image (not a fragment of an image) over a socket.

I have tried several approaches unsuccessfully.
My first attempt was using a node gstreamer library and use gstreamer to decode the udp and re encode as images.

My second attempt was using ffmpeg library.
Here is the code below :

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const dgram = require("dgram");
const ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

const io = socketIO(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:3001",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3001",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  })
);

const udpServer = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A client connected");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("A client disconnected");
  });
});

// Function to decode an H.264 video frame
function decodeH264Video(inputData, callback) {
  const command = ffmpeg()
    .input(inputData)
    .inputFormat("h264")
    .inputOptions(["-c:v h264"])
    .toFormat("image2")
    .on("end", () => {
      console.log("Decoding complete");
    })
    .on("error", (err) => {
      console.error("Error decoding video:", err);
    })
    .pipe();

  callback(command);
}

// Function to convert a decoded video frame to an image (JPEG format)
function convertVideoFrameToImage(decodedData, callback) {
  const imageStream = decodedData.pipe();
  const imageBuffer = [];

  imageStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
    imageBuffer.push(chunk);
  });

  imageStream.on("end", () => {
    const imageData = Buffer.concat(imageBuffer);
    callback(imageData);
  });
}

udpServer.on("message", (message) => {
  // Decode the UDP packet containing H.264 encoded video
  decodeH264Video(message, (decodedVideo) => {
    // Process the decoded video frame and convert it to an image
    convertVideoFrameToImage(decodedVideo, (imageData) => {
      // Send the image data to connected clients
      io.sockets.emit("image", { imageData: imageData.toString("base64") });
    });
  });
});

udpServer.bind(5000);

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Any help is more than welcome